# Can block sizes be customized in Squarespace?

Tags: squarespace

I am adding custom animation to a Squarespace button using JavaScript. However, when you add a button block, the borders of the block are larger than the actual button. I know you can add spacers on each size to shrink the block space a little, but I'm still having problems with my animation being activated when hovering in the button's surrounding area. The spacers are only letting me adjust block sizes so much.

Is there a way around this, or did I just learn a major limitation of Squarespace?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: yes.

Can you provide code samples? Your question is a too vague to know how to solve it. It would also be helpful if you let us know if you're using developer mode to know if you'll have to use CSS/JS through the [custom css](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor) area or [code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection) or if you have access to the template files.

You can just override the Squarespace button block padding through CSS (in your template files or the custom CSS interface).

```
     .sqs-block-button {
          padding: 10px 15px;
     }
```

Although I'm not sure if you're referring to the button block or the grid system's column padding.

If you're referring to the grid system it will probably be more difficult, since you'll have to override lots of the system CSS.

Please clarify so we can help.